# Switch Video Position and Play Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, video, position

I have a site with a video on it. It also has three divs.

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle> contains table </div>
<div id="bottom></div>
```

Now, what I would like to do, is have the video in the "top" div, and play. Once that is done, I want it to go to the "bottom" div and play. Once that is done, I want it to go back to the "top" div and play, and so on.

How would I go about doing this? Because I can't seem to get it working.
Currently I have this, which doesn't work:

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("play", function(){
        var vidTop = document.getElementById('top').appendChild(document.getElementById('myVideo'));
        });

        document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("ended", function(){
        var vidBottom = document.getElementById('bottom').appendChild(document.getElementById('myVideo'));
        var vidLoop = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        function playVid(){
        vidLoop.play();
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

So all I have so far is this, as requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div id="top">
    <p>top</p>
</div>

<div id="middle">
    <table style="width:1000px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="33%"><iframe src="https//slashdot.org" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></iframe></td>
            <td align="center" width="33%"><iframe src="http//slashdot.org" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></iframe></td>
            <td algin="center" width="33%"><iframe src="http://slashdot.org" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></iframe></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="33%"><iframe src="http://slashdot.org" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></iframe></td>
            <td align="center" width="33%"><iframe src="http://slashdot.org" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></iframe></td>
            <td align="center" width="33%"><iframe src="http://slashdot.org" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></iframe></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="bottom">
    <p>bottom</p>
</div>

<div id="video">
    <video id="myVideo" controls autoplay width="300" height="200">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>

<div id="javascriptSource">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</div>

<div id="script">
    <script>
        document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("play", function(){
        var vidTop = document.getElementById('top').appendChild(document.getElementById('myVideo'));
        });

        document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("ended", function(){
        var vidBottom = document.getElementById('bottom').appendChild(document.getElementById('myVideo'));
        var vidLoop = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        function playVid(){
        vidLoop.play();
        }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I am completely new to JavaScript. I tried using the information from w3schools but I am obviously making some basic mistakes somewhere.

Comment: can you post your complete code with css

Comment: Updated it as requested

Comment: and where is css?

Comment: can you elaborate "Now, what I would like to do, is have the video in the "top" div, and play? Once that is done, I want it to go to the "bottom" div and play. Once that is done, I want it to go back to the "top" div and play, and so on."

Comment: Sure. What I mean is that when you open the webpage, I want the video on the top of the page, and play. Once it has finished playing, I want it to be below the table, so that you only see the table in plain view.
Then it is playing below a couple of times, and after a certain number of times I want to to play back on the top of the page.
I don't have css. Do I need it?

Comment: ok so once video play has been completed it will shift the position next to table right

Comment: 1. play video above table one time. 2. video done playing. 3. video plays below table 50 times. 4. video done playing 50 times. 5. video plays above table one time.

Comment: It take time but I shall give you solution right

Comment: Hey I did it look my answer give me your feedback, I used jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var computeTime = 0;
  var bottomComputeTime = 0;
  var LoopComputeLimit = 50;
  
  var divVideo = $("<div/>")
    .attr({
      class: "divVideo"
    }).html("<video id=\"myVideo\" controls autoplay width=\"300\" height=\"200\"><source src=\"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>");

  resetPositionToTop();

  $("#myVideo").unbind("ended").bind("ended", function(e) {
    console.log("bottomComputeTime:", bottomComputeTime,"computeTime:",computeTime);

    if (computeTime === 0) {
      resetPositionToBottom();
    }

    if (bottomComputeTime < LoopComputeLimit) {
      bottomComputeTime++;
      $("#myVideo").get(0).play();
    } else if (bottomComputeTime === LoopComputeLimit) {
      bottomComputeTime = 0;
      computeTime = 0;
      resetPositionToTop();
      $("#myVideo").get(0).play();
    }
  });

  function resetPositionToTop() {
    divVideo.appendTo(".top");
  }

  function resetPositionToBottom() {
    divVideo.appendTo(".bottom");
  }

});
```

```css
*{
  font-family:"arial";
  font-size:12px;
}
div{
  text-align:center;
  margin:5px 0px  ;
}
#divVideo{
  float:left;
}
.top{
  min-height:200px;
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
.middle{
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
.middle table {
  width:100%;
}
.bottom{
  min-height:200px;
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="top">
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" width="33%">
          Middle section
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works with your video, however not with mine. In the same folder as this code, I have a video named video.mp4 however if I type that as source, it does not load.

Comment: rick code is not bound to any video URL it's independent. You should add your mp4 file with proper absolute URL.

Absolute URL eg: http://localhost/mysite/media/video/video.mp4

Comment: my friend code has been tested in my local machine with only video file it name and it is working fine

Comment: you probably made some mistake

Comment: This is my full answer code's github https://github.com/dipakchavda2912/stackoverflow-resolved-answers

Comment: Still if do not get your answer then let me know because if I should write relative path then the video will not working in StackOverflow code demo

Comment: I would like the code for a relative path please :)

Comment: even if you see my repo you may get an answer automatically.

Comment: Even again I said absolute path is better, if you do not wish then you may use relative path and verify your path carefully and then add it.

Comment: Use your logic and think if my code works with absolute path then it will work with also relative path and logic is not related with the path, man.....

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking as well, which is why it didn't make sense to me that it wasn't working. I've reuploaded everything and now it works great. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Rick that is why I take create about to give review comments and code carefully, then give negative or positive vote or comments in StackOverflow.